# How do I create something as shown below (volume change indicator) in linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, image

I would like to show an image with transparent background to indicate something when a key combination is pressed.
[image]

Let's say I pressed ctrl+f3, I trigger a python script. Is there anyway I can make that happen?
What python library can I use to show an image without window border and background?

- I have figured out how to trigger the file on key press. How to I deal with the (imshow) thing?
  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*show an image without window border and background*

This sound like task for some GUI library. There are many available but you would need test them in order to find which one can do it. First feature is generally known as *frameless* or *borderless* window. `tkinter` which ships with python has ability to work this way, see for example [tutorialspoint.com tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/creating-a-frameless-window-in-python-tkinter), though I do not know how it will work with alpha channel of your image.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't mentioned this but, the window should stay active for some time and leave(close) automatically. So basically recreating the volume change indicator. I am fine with working with other languages if I have to...